# How to return List from Task.WhenAll instead of array

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, task-parallel-library, task

I'm trying to find a solution to this but but haven't been able to find one. That's why I'm asking here.

I have a list of tasks with two items

```
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
tasks.Add(Task.FromResult(1));
tasks.Add(Task.FromResult(2));
```

When I call `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, it returns `int[]` but I want it to return `List<int>`. Like below:

```
List<int> result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I want to be able to add new items to the list after it's created.

Comment: and why do you want that?

Comment: I want to add new item in the list after I've the result.

Comment: How to convert an `array` to a `List`, using `ToList()` call, simple

Comment: Down voters, please explain why?

Comment: I have down voted, as no verification is  done while writing the code or debugging, if a `Task` returns a type T and all tasks in a given `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` have same type , then always `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, will unwrap it as `T[]`, now your question is how to translate `T[]` to `List<T>`, over an above you have mentioned that this doesn't work `await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ToList()`, do you genuinely expect Task.ToList() to work ?

Comment: I think the idea here is eliding the `await` keyword. If I have a `Task<IEnumerable<T>` method returning `Task.WhenAll`, it won't work because `Task.WhenAll` returns `Task<T[]>`. Sure, you can await and then mark the method async, but that's more inefficient, as you're unwrapping the Task just to wrap it again. Still, doesn't appear there's a way around that.

Comment: As a side note, it is always possible to cast implicitly an array to `IList<T>`: `IList<int> result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can write:

```
List<int> result = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).ToList();
```

This will convert the array to a list.

Do not forget to add the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: It tried this `await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ToList();` and it was not worked. but I put brackets like that `(await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).ToList();`, it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Saadi do you use the editor to check the return type of `Task.WhenAll(tasks)`, it would be a Task type, which cannot be converted to a `List` using ToList()